# Laravel: form method != save method?

Tags: laravel, forms, save

I am new to Laravel coming from CakePHP where the form and save method for a form is one and the same function name. I saw in many Laravel tutorials that the from method (that displays the form) is different than the method to save form (that actually saves data). Why using 2 different method names?

For example what's wrong with:

```
pub function xyz(Request $request)
{
if($results->isMethod('post')){ 
... then save and return redirect 
} 
... the code for showing the form in case there is no POST.
```

then having 2 routes one for GET and one for POST on the same url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because people like to filter out things at route level not in controller, Also it helps developer to apply middleware grouping for each route separately. so that they can apply roles and permission etc. easily at route level.

It will looks horrible if mix all things in controller.

Think about middleware and groups in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you don't wanna mix a lot of logic in the same method .  The case you have simple is the simple scenario . But there will be case where you wanna pass initial data in the create form . You have to write logic for that also in the same method and while you store the data you need to do the validation and calculate other business logic . If you combine all those things in one method it will mix all the things in one method and code difficult to read